# Where in the source code should I create an object?

Tags: objective-c, class, scope

I want to create an object from a class that I have created.  What I have been trying is to create the object (which can be testingclass) from a method of another class, which I will call classexample, but it says that testingclass is undeclared, which I assumed meant that it was out of the scope of the method, and the method couldn't access it.  My program doesn't have a main function like in c or anything so I don't really understand where to put code that involves different objects if it can't go in methods.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the header file of the testingclass and did you import it to the file that create that object? That's all I can guess for your problems with very little information for very strange problem.